# Unable to ssh from windows 10 machine

Tags: ssh, windows-10, putty, cygwin

Im trying to ssh a machine from my Windows 10 machine using a linux shell.

I tried using Bash programm included in Windows 10 and i have got the following error:
"Resource temporarily unavailable"

I tried then using Cygwin but i have got the following error:
"Connection timeout"

I tried then using a virtualbox VM but i have got the following error:
"Connection timeout"

It only works with Putty client but it is not a shell

Does anybody know how to makes it work with Windows 10 Bash, Cygwin or a Virtual Box VM ?

Thank you

Comment: Windows 10 WSL Bash is a known issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1098526/windows-10-linux-subsystem-ssh-client-resource-temporarily-unavailable

Comment: For the others, double-check your connection settings. Make sure you're connecting to the right port and IP that putty is connecting to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check the workaround proposed and related to Win 10 WSL Bash. For other i m not sure this is related to connection settings as it works fine with Putty on the same machine

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, when you install Nginx, it will block SSH by default with the error message "Resource temporarily unavailable" unless you...

> sudo ufw allow ssh